# How can fix learning rate with text classification on tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, sentiment-analysis, text-classification

I have been coding sentiment analysis model with tensorflow keras.
I am using csv dataset which has labels(pos:1, neg:0) in row 1 and English texts in row 2.
The results I expect is to show number between 0 and 1 when I input some texts through txt file.
However, though I set model, the loss rate is keeping negative score and accuracy rate is not increasing, including validation rates.
I do not know what the matter is. Thus, I attached my codes. 
Thank you very much.

```
import csv
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences

vocab_size = 20000
embedding_dim = 16
max_length = 120
trunc_type='post'
padding_type='post'
oov_tok = "<OOV>"
training_portion = .8

sentences = []
labels = []
stopwords = [ "a", "about", "above", "after", "again", "against", "all", "am", "an", "any", "are", 
"as", "at", "be", "because", "been", "before", "being", "below", "between", "both", "but", "by", 
"could", "did", "do", "does", "doing", "down", "during", "each", "few", "for", "from", "further", 
"had", "has", "have", "having", "he", "he'd", "he'll", "he's", "her", "here", "here's", "hers", 
"herself", "him", "himself", "his", "how", "how's", "i", "i'd", "i'll", "i'm", "i've", "if", "in", 
"into", "is", "it", "it's", "its", "itself", "let's", "me", "more", "most", "my", "myself", "nor", 
"of", "on", "once", "only", "or", "other", "ought", "our", "ours", "ourselves", "out", "over", "own", 
"same", "she", "she'd", "she'll", "she's", "should", "so", "some", "such", "than", "that", "that's", 
"the", "their", "theirs", "them", "themselves", "then", "there", "there's", "these", "they", 
"they'd", "they'll", "they're", "they've", "this", "those", "through", "to", "too", "under", "until", 
"up", "very", "was", "we", "we'd", "we'll", "we're", "we've", "were", "what", "what's", "when", 
"when's", "where", "where's", "which", "while", "who", "who's", "whom", "why", "why's", "with", 
"would", "you", "you'd", "you'll", "you're", "you've", "your", "yours", "yourself", "yourselves" ]
print(len(stopwords)

with open("/train.csv", 'r', encoding='latin1') as csvfile:
reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
next(reader)
for row in reader:
    labels.append(row[0])
    sentence = row[1]
    for word in stopwords:
        token = " " + word + " "
        sentence = sentence.replace(token, " ")
    sentences.append(sentence)

train_size = int(len(sentences) * training_portion)

train_sentences = sentences[:train_size]
train_labels = labels[:train_size]

validation_sentences = sentences[train_size:]
validation_labels = labels[train_size:]

tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words = vocab_size, oov_token=oov_tok)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(train_sentences)
word_index = tokenizer.word_index

train_sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(train_sentences)
train_padded = pad_sequences(train_sequences, padding=padding_type, maxlen=max_length)

validation_sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(validation_sentences)
validation_padded = pad_sequences(validation_sequences, padding=padding_type, maxlen=max_length)

label_tokenizer = Tokenizer()
label_tokenizer.fit_on_texts(labels)

training_label_seq = np.array(label_tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(train_labels))
validation_label_seq = np.array(label_tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(validation_labels))

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, 64),
tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(128,  return_sequences=True)),
tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32)),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu'),
tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
])
model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
          optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(1e-4),
          metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()

history = model.fit(train_padded, training_label_seq, epochs=6,
                validation_data=(validation_padded, validation_label_seq),
                validation_steps=30)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMy1q.png)

Comment: You should be using a sigmoid activation in the last layer, that will fix the problem.

Comment: I added sigmoid activation in the last layer which is 'tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)'. However, though the digit becomes low, it is still negative and the accuracy rate maintains no less than 0.5000.

Comment: Can you please provide the CSV dataset you used so we can inspect and reproduced it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are applying tokenizer on labels as well which will convert the labels `0` and `1` to `1` and `2`  which confused the classifier, since tf.keras Tokenizer word.index starts from index 1(not 0).

Below was the target labels causing negative loss by confusing the classifier.

```
label_tokenizer.word_index
```

> {'0': 1, '1': 2}.

Below is the modified code on sample data which is giving positive loss values as expected.

```
import csv
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
import pandas as pd 

vocab_size = 20000
embedding_dim = 16
max_length = 120
trunc_type='post'
padding_type='post'
oov_tok = "<OOV>"
training_portion = .8

sentences = []
labels = []
stopwords = [ "a", "about", "above", "after", "again", "against", "all", "am", "an", "any", "are", 
"as", "at", "be", "because", "been", "before", "being", "below", "between", "both", "but", "by", 
"could", "did", "do", "does", "doing", "down", "during", "each", "few", "for", "from", "further", 
"had", "has", "have", "having", "he", "he'd", "he'll", "he's", "her", "here", "here's", "hers", 
"herself", "him", "himself", "his", "how", "how's", "i", "i'd", "i'll", "i'm", "i've", "if", "in", 
"into", "is", "it", "it's", "its", "itself", "let's", "me", "more", "most", "my", "myself", "nor", 
"of", "on", "once", "only", "or", "other", "ought", "our", "ours", "ourselves", "out", "over", "own", 
"same", "she", "she'd", "she'll", "she's", "should", "so", "some", "such", "than", "that", "that's", 
"the", "their", "theirs", "them", "themselves", "then", "there", "there's", "these", "they", 
"they'd", "they'll", "they're", "they've", "this", "those", "through", "to", "too", "under", "until", 
"up", "very", "was", "we", "we'd", "we'll", "we're", "we've", "were", "what", "what's", "when", 
"when's", "where", "where's", "which", "while", "who", "who's", "whom", "why", "why's", "with", 
"would", "you", "you'd", "you'll", "you're", "you've", "your", "yours", "yourself", "yourselves" ]
print(len(stopwords)) 

with open("train.csv", 'r', encoding='latin1') as csvfile:
  reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
  next(reader)
  for row in reader:
      labels.append(int(row[0]))
      sentence = row[1]
      for word in stopwords:
          token = " " + word + " "
          sentence = sentence.replace(token, " ")
      sentences.append(sentence) 

train_size = int(len(sentences) * training_portion)

train_sentences = sentences[:train_size]
train_labels = np.array(labels[:train_size])

validation_sentences = sentences[train_size:]
validation_labels = np.array(labels[train_size:])

tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words = vocab_size, oov_token=oov_tok)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(train_sentences)
word_index = tokenizer.word_index

train_sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(train_sentences)
train_padded = pad_sequences(train_sequences, padding=padding_type, maxlen=max_length)

validation_sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(validation_sentences)
validation_padded = pad_sequences(validation_sequences, padding=padding_type, maxlen=max_length) 


model = tf.keras.Sequential([
tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, 64),
tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(128,  return_sequences=True)),
tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32)),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu'),
tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(1,activation="sigmoid")
])
model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
          optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(1e-4),
          metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()

history = model.fit(train_padded, train_labels, epochs=6,
                validation_data=(validation_padded, validation_labels),
                validation_steps=30)
```

**Output:**

```
Model: "sequential_2"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
embedding_2 (Embedding)      (None, None, 64)          1280000   
_________________________________________________________________
bidirectional_4 (Bidirection (None, None, 256)         197632    
_________________________________________________________________
bidirectional_5 (Bidirection (None, 64)                73984     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_6 (Dense)              (None, 64)                4160      
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_4 (Dropout)          (None, 64)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_7 (Dense)              (None, 16)                1040      
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_5 (Dropout)          (None, 16)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_8 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 17        
=================================================================
Total params: 1,556,833
Trainable params: 1,556,833
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
Epoch 1/6
191/191 [==============================] - 71s 371ms/step - loss: 0.7135 - accuracy: 0.5783 - val_loss: 0.6934 - val_accuracy: 0.5345
Epoch 2/6
191/191 [==============================] - 71s 369ms/step - loss: 0.6943 - accuracy: 0.5793 - val_loss: 0.6932 - val_accuracy: 0.5345
Epoch 3/6
191/191 [==============================] - 71s 370ms/step - loss: 0.6936 - accuracy: 0.5791 - val_loss: 0.6932 - val_accuracy: 0.5345
Epoch 4/6
191/191 [==============================] - 70s 369ms/step - loss: 0.6934 - accuracy: 0.5793 - val_loss: 0.6932 - val_accuracy: 0.5345
Epoch 5/6
191/191 [==============================] - 71s 371ms/step - loss: 0.6934 - accuracy: 0.5793 - val_loss: 0.6932 - val_accuracy: 0.5345
Epoch 6/6
191/191 [==============================] - 72s 375ms/step - loss: 0.6933 - accuracy: 0.5793 - val_loss: 0.6931 - val_accuracy: 0.5345
```

Comment: @Chu SeongYeub - If your issue is resolved from the above answer, please accept and upvote the answer.